# How to calculate the inflection point with python?

Tags: python, numpy, plot

I want to calculate the inflection point with python.

This is my code, which I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as m
import loaddataa as ld
import scipy.integrate as inte

# Loading of the values
dataListStride = ld.loadData("../Projektpraktikum Binder/Data/1 Fabienne/Test1/left foot/50cm")
indexStrideData = 0 
strideData = dataListStride[indexStrideData]

#%%Calculation of the horizontal acceleration

def horizontal(yAngle, yAcceleration, xAcceleration):
     a = ((m.cos(m.radians(yAngle)))*yAcceleration)-((m.sin(m.radians(yAngle)))*xAcceleration)
     return a

resultsHorizontal = list()

for i in range (len(strideData)):
    strideData_yAngle = strideData.to_numpy()[i, 2]
    strideData_xAcceleration = strideData.to_numpy()[i, 4]
    strideData_yAcceleration = strideData.to_numpy()[i, 5]
    resultsHorizontal.append(horizontal(strideData_yAngle, strideData_yAcceleration, strideData_xAcceleration))

resultsHorizontal.insert(0, 0)

print("The values are: " +str(resultsHorizontal))

print("These are " +str(len(resultsHorizontal)) + " values.")

#x-axis "convert" into time: 100 Hertz makes 0.01 seconds
scale_factor = 0.01 
x_values = np.arange(len(resultsHorizontal)) * scale_factor


plt.plot(x_values[:-1],strideData.iloc[:,7]) # plot heel strike (1)
plt.plot(x_values[:-1],strideData.iloc[:,9]) # plot heel lift (2)

plt.plot(x_values, resultsHorizontal)

#%% Integration of horizontal acceleration
velocity = inte.cumtrapz(resultsHorizontal,x_values)
plt.plot(x_values[:-1], velocity)

#%% Integration of Velocity
s = inte.cumtrapz(velocity, x_values[:-1])
plt.plot(x_values[:-2],s)
```

[image]

I would like to determine the inflection point (red point). Could someone help me please to solve this? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: You will need to define *inflection point* for your discrete data? There are some choices of what you want to call an inflection point in that case. You could say that it is a node at which the discrete derivatives change signs. You could mean some estimation [like this](https://veltech.edu.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Paper-04-2016.pdf), or maybe inflection points of some smooth interpolation.

Comment: Adding to @NotDijkstra's request, the problem isn't well-posed in general. If you assume that your data is a sample of a smooth function and has some sampling error, without adding some additional information to the problem (e.g. by choosing an interpolation) it's impossible to know whether a small squiggle is a real feature in the data or if it's due to some kind of sampling error.

Comment: Okay you're right.It is so that I would like to calculate the middle, i.e. what normally represents the inflection Point (Turning Point).  So the red dot.  Is there a way to do that?  And yes, they are usually discrete values that Python simply connects when plotting.